# Spring Boot Environment-specific configurations

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, environment, microservices

I have a spring boot application that uses the **actuator, auto-configuration and JPA**. I want to be able to use an in-memory DB in my **test** profile, a MySQL DB configuration during **development** and a separate **production** DB configuration when the app is deployed in production. Presumably from the java command line I should be able to specify the environment and the right configuration file or config block in **application.properties** (or .yml) will be picked up.

I have not found a good post with example describing how to do this switching so I thought I'd ask if anyone has a good example. My main aim is to pre-define the `spring.datasource` and `spring.jpa` properties at build time and then at run-time switch the app config per environment "dynamically" using the java command line argument. Secondary goal would be to do the same with the `management` configurations, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Richard for the mention of `spring.profiles.active` JVM variable. Since my question was specific to the way **Spring Boot** does this and since there is much more to the answer, I am inclined to answer this myself and include all the details of how I arrived at the answer in the hopes that it will save others time.

First, you can indeed pick the correct profile on the `java` command line by adding `-Dspring.profiles.active=profile_name` when you are running your Spring Boot app. (this is assuming your deployment preference is an **uber jar with embedded container** - Tomcat in my case)

I wanted to leave **MySQL** datasource configurations under the *default* profile and put **H2** in-memory datasource configuration under a *test* profile. However, the way Spring Boot picks the right **datasource** based on profile is not so obvious. Even though I had MySQL details under the *default* profile and I had the in-memory H2 datasource details under the *test* profile, it would still pick H2 as the datasource even when `spring.profiles.active` was omitted from the command line. This was contrary to my assumption  that *default* profile will be picked, well, by default :-)

I ended up having to put H2 configuration under the *default* profile and then create a ***local*** profile that included the MySQL datasource configuration. Here's what I ended up with in my `application.yml`

```
spring:
  profiles: default 

spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:sampletest;MODE=MySQL

---
spring:
  profiles: test

spring.jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop

---
spring:
  profiles: local

spring.datasource:
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sampledev
  username: sample
  password: sample

spring.jpa:
  hibernate:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
    ddl-auto: update
```

This worked. I was able to switch between *default* profiles and the *local* profile by omitting or adding the `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` on the `java` command line. Because test profile inherits from default it is also using H2

One more nuance: I added `ddl-auto: create-drop` to the *test* profile which uses the  in-memory DB to facilitate automatic table creation / teardown for unit tests. But for the local profile which uses MySQL I changed it to `update`. Implication being that for the local profile I have to first create the database outside of the application.

Comment: By way of update, if you are using the maven spring-boot:run plugin, you can choose the active profile this way:  ```mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=myProfile" -Dsome.other.application.property=x```

Comment: Thanking someone does not add value to the answer. Please consider rewriting the answer with a reader having only the question as context.

Answer (score 0):

this article shows how to use spring profiles, available in spring 3.1 and later.  It will do exactly what you want.

http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/spring-3-1-environment-profiles-2/

set a JVM variable like this: spring.profiles.active=development

then in your configuration xml you can wrap environment specific xml with the profile tags

```
<beans profiles="development">  
  <bean id="dataSource" class="..."></bean>
  <bean id="messagingProvider" class="..."></bean>
</beans>
```

You can also set the profile on annotation-driven classes with @Profile("development") at the beginning of the class.  That class will only be autowired if the profile matches.

For unit tests you can set the active profile on a test class with @ActiveProfile(profiles = "test", "CI"), it will run using test and CI resources

Comment: Thank you Richard. I don't think applying the annotation to spring boot beans will work because the classes have to work in every environment but I think I will try "spring.profiles.active" and see if that works. I also found reference to this method [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)